# SSE delay on IBM bluemix with spring (java) on liberty

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am trying to make the server sent event (SSE) work on IBM Bluemix.
I am working on a Spring test project which works with Microsoft Azure with a 15s TTFB. Here, with bluemix, it is more like 5 minutes !
The rest of the application works great by the way.
I don't really understand why and I can't find explaination... maybe there is a config to give to liberty through the manifest.yml file ?
If you have any idea, please let me know !
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Hi, same problem here. Did you find a way to solve your problem ? I asked their team and the only answer I got was : "You cannot stream HTTP responses from CF on Bluemix.  You can use websockets for similar use case."